# how to test to see if my breakers are still functional

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I live in a older home that doesn't have enough circuits for all the things ppl must plugged in, in today's modern world, I used to trip the breaker for the garage all the time when i would weld out there, but now the power has gone out in a couple rooms ( the plugs and lights aren't working) I have checked the breakers and none of them have been tripped i tried turning them all on and off (the Breakers) and there is still nothing how can i troubleshoot this? How can I check to see if my breakers are still functioning properly?

Comment: Breakers are just a bit more complicated switch.  Usually the easy way to test is to use a multi-meter carefully.  A picture of the panel will help.  Some older panel makes are not safe.  Usually breakers are not the problem, loose/broken connections are more common.

Comment: First, look for a tripped GFCI or (unlikely in an older home) AFCI device that needs to be reset.  [Edit]ing in clear pictures of your panel and it's labelling will be helpful in considering whether that panel and breakers are a fire waiting (you hope waiting) to happen or perfectly good and reliable even if 60 years old.

Comment: Is the garage close to the meter/fuse box?  I am just wondering if your welding burnt out some cables. For next time,  when a breaker trips, dont just reset and ignore.  They are there to protect cables and people.